# Matching BigInts in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm currently in the process of learning scala, and I'm looking for some best practices/proper idioms for the use of pattern matching with `BigInt`s.  I'm writing some algorithmic code (for Project Euler) as a way to learn the language.

The problem I am running into is what is the best idiomatic way to match a `BigInt`, since there's a type conversion problem if I try to write `case 1 =>` and `BigInt` isn't a `case class`.  Is there a canonical way to do this, or should I just give up and use `if` statements?

The following is one possible pattern:

```
def pollardRho(n: BigInt): BigInt = {
  val one = BigInt(1)

  n match {
    case `one` => n
    //additional cases here
  }
}
```

This one just feels wrong: A hack to get around the fact that I can't match it directly, especially with the backticks in there to keep scala from trying to assign the resulting value to `one` or when I have to do it for more than a single value or in a single case.

Another possibility:

```
def pollardRho(n: BigInt): BigInt = {

  n match {
    case _ if n == 1 => n
    //additional cases here
  }
}
```

This sort of pattern appeals to the Erlang programmer in me, but I have some concerns:

1. Given the [warnings I've read not to treat Scala like any other language](http://twitter.github.com/effectivescala/#Introduction), I am not sure that my instinct here is not an anti-pattern (or at least considered less readable) in the scala world.
2. It feels like there might be cleaner way to use a custom `PartialFunction` instead of `n match` if what I am fundamentally going to do is just a series of tests around `n`.  I am not sure, however, exactly what that would look like (most of the examples of `PartialFunction`s I've seen don't look quite like this application).

My question is, out of the array of possibilities in scala, which one is the best/most readable/most idiomatic?

Answer (score 4):

Write your own [extractor](http://codemonkeyism.com/scala-goodness-extractors/):

```
object Big {
  def unapply(n:BigInt) = Some(n.toInt)
}

//usage
def f(b:BigInt) = b match {
   case Big(0) => "none"
   case Big(1) => "one"
   case _ => "many"
}
```

Obviously, this isn't the fastest solution, but I think, it's quite idiomatic...

Comment: This also doesn't produce the desired output, since it assumes that I am working with something that can convert to `Int` without overflow, e.g., `BigInt("4294967297")` will match `Big(1)`.

Comment: The logic in this one might not be 100% correct but extract is definitely the way to go if you want to be able to use match.

Comment: I'd use `n.toLong` as you can't write literal number, bigger than `Long`. Besides it's natural to use `String` extractor along with `Long` one, so you could use use `case Big("123") => ` as well.